# One producer thread and multiple non-blocking simultaneous consumer threads (MROW) python

Tags: python, multithreading, synchronization, nonblocking

I have one producer thread reading some data and processing them and other threads reading that that, I was using a condition variable in the producer in order to avoid busy wait and notify when the new adquisition of data is ready, but every consumer takes the lock when they wanna read that data so the other consumer threads have to wait, what would be the better aproach to get all the consumers read the data at once when the producer is done?,

Here is some of the code:

The produccer:

```
condition = threading.Condition()


def get_data():
while(1):
    global actumulated_data, sdev1, mean1, number_of_adq, instant_data
    time.sleep(1.3660619/1000000.0)
    number_of_adq = number_of_adq + 1
    fpga.write_int('adc_data_ctrl',0)
    fpga.write_int('adc_data_ctrl',7)
    data = fpga.read('adc_data_bram',8192,0)
    data2 = map(hex, map(ord, data))
    for i in range(8192):
        data2[i] = fix8_7(twos_comp(int(data2[i],16),8))
    condition.acquire() # condition variable
    instant_data = numpy.array(data2)
    actumulated_data = numpy.concatenate((actumulated_data,instant_data),axis=0)    
    condition.notifyAll()
    condition.release()
```

One of the consumers:

```
def plot_adc_out():
while(1):
    condition.acquire()
    plt.clf()
    plt.plot(instant_data)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlim(0, len(instant_data))
    plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
    plt.draw()
    condition.wait()
    condition.release()
```

So there is a few consumers like this one, I was thinking on something like in C++ with read and write locks in which if the lock is write lock is gonna be blocking but if is a reader lock is non blocking so can be a lot of threads reading that item at the same time.

[Readers–writer lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock)

```
pthread_rwlock_wrlock
pthread_rwlock_rdlock
```

But I belive that python dosen't have read and write locks.

Comment: Could you add some code to understand the problem better?

Comment: @Miquel I added some code over there and some extra info, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way for threads to communicate is by using locks, but the queue.Queue data structure offers a much more convenient mechanism for inter-thread communication, with all the ugly locking stuff comfortably hidden under the covers. Here's an example adapted from from my O'Reilly School of Technology classes that converts a string to upper case using by piping each character to a separate thread. Note the code below is Python 3, but it is easily adapted to Python 2.

Everything is started off by the control thread (which imports the output and worker threads shown below from their respective modules). It first creates the input and output queues. These are standard FIFOs, with a limit of 50% more than the number of worker threads to avoid locking up too much memory in buffered objects. Then it creates and starts the output thread, and finally creates and starts as many worker threads as configured by the WORKERS constant. Worker threads get from the input queue and put to the output queue.

```
"""
control.py: Creates queues, starts output and worker threads,
            and pushes inputs into the input queue.
"""
from queue import Queue
from output import OutThread
from worker import WorkerThread

WORKERS = 10

inq = Queue(maxsize=int(WORKERS*1.5))
outq = Queue(maxsize=int(WORKERS*1.5))

ot = OutThread(WORKERS, outq)
ot.start()

for i in range(WORKERS):
    w = WorkerThread(inq, outq)
    w.start()
instring = input("Words of wisdom: ")
for work in enumerate(instring):
    inq.put(work)
for i in range(WORKERS):
    inq.put(None)
inq.join()
print("Control thread terminating")
```

The Worker threads have been cast so as to make interactions easy. The work units received from the input queue are (index, character) pairs, and the output units are also pairs. The processing is split out into a separate method to make subclassing easier—simply override the process() method.

```
"""
worker.py: a sample worker thread that receives input
           through one Queue and routes output through another.
"""
from threading import Thread

class WorkerThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, iq, oq, *args, **kw):
        """Initialize thread and save Queue references."""
        Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.iq, self.oq = iq, oq
    def run(self):
        while True:
            work = self.iq.get()
            if work is None:
                self.oq.put(None)
                print("Worker", self.name, "done")
                self.iq.task_done()
                break
            i, c = work
            result = (i, self.process(c)) # this is the "work"
            self.oq.put(result)
            self.iq.task_done()
    def process(self, s):
        """This defines how the string is processed to produce a result"""
        return s.upper()
```

The output thread simply has to extract output packets from a queue where they are placed by the worker threads. As each worker thread terminates, it posts a None to the queue. When a None has been received from each thread, the output thread terminates. The output thread is told on initialization how many worker threads there are, and each time it receives another None it decrements the worker count until eventually there are no workers left. At that point, the output thread terminates. Since the worker threads aren't guaranteed to return in any particular order the results can be sorted. Without sorting you can see the order the results arrived in.

```
"""
output.py: The output thread for the miniature framework.
"""
identity = lambda x: x

import threading
class OutThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, N, q, sorting=True, *args, **kw):
        """Initialize thread and save queue reference."""
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
        self.queue = q
        self.workers = N
        self.sorting = sorting
        self.output = []
    def run(self):
        """Extract items from the output queue and print until all done."""
        while self.workers:
            p = self.queue.get()
            if p is None:
                self.workers -= 1
            else:
                # This is a real output packet
                self.output.append(p)
        print("".join(c for (i, c) in (sorted if self.sorting else identity)(self.output)))
        print ("Output thread terminating"
```

Comment: Thnks for your awnser @holdenweb, but that kind of queue are LIFO o FIFO so once the consumer call the method get is gonna remove from the queue the item and I need several threads read the same item in a parallel way.

Comment: In which case provide each worker with its own unique input queue instead os using a single shared queue, and put a copy of the input on  each worker's queue. Apologies for the misunderstanding.

Comment: The thing is that I'm reading and proccesing a lot of data in every 1.3uS, so copying to each working queue would't be too efficient and I don't think that the computer can deal with that.

Comment: Copying isn't required - each thread would receive a reference to the same data object. But I accept that you want to keep the overhead low and will let you move on.

Answer (score 0):

If you do end up using locks for anything, I'd suggest using 'with' rather than acquiring and releasing explicitly..

```
with self._some_lock:
    # Do some stuff that accesses a shared resource
    self._shared_resource = some_value
```

That'll do all the ugly stuff for you and has the advantage of indenting the locked code so that it's harder to make simple mistakes (like returning before releasing the lock etc...)

Answer (score 0):

Below is a python (3+) implementation of the ReadWriteLock, takes care of the writer starvation issue and supports promotion of read lock to write lock, if requested for during construction. It utilizes only one Lock and a Condition.

Rewriting the Producer using this Lock class and the WriteRWLock context manager class -

```
rwLock = ReadWriteLock()

def get_data():
while(1):
    global actumulated_data, sdev1, mean1, number_of_adq, instant_data
    time.sleep(1.3660619/1000000.0)
    number_of_adq = number_of_adq + 1
    fpga.write_int('adc_data_ctrl',0)
    fpga.write_int('adc_data_ctrl',7)
    data = fpga.read('adc_data_bram',8192,0)
    data2 = map(hex, map(ord, data))
    for i in range(8192):
        data2[i] = fix8_7(twos_comp(int(data2[i],16),8))
    with WriteRWLock(rwLock):  # Guard object acquiring a Write Lock
        instant_data = numpy.array(data2)
        actumulated_data = numpy.concatenate((actumulated_data,instant_data),axis=0)
```

Rewriting the Consumer, using the ReadRWLock context manager class -

```
def plot_adc_out():
while(1):
    with ReadRWLock(rwLock):    # Guard object acquiring a Read Lock
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(instant_data)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.xlim(0, len(instant_data))
        plt.ylim(-1.5,1.5)
        plt.draw()
```

With the above code, you can have multiple consumers using the instant_data in parallel.

The complete ReadWriteLock class and the required context managers.

```
# From O'Reilly Python Cookbook by David Ascher, Alex Martelli
# With changes to cover the starvation situation where a continuous
#   stream of readers may starve a writer, Lock Promotion and Context Managers

class ReadWriteLock:
  """ A lock object that allows many simultaneous "read locks", but
  only one "write lock." """

  def __init__(self, withPromotion=False):
    self._read_ready = threading.Condition(threading.RLock(  ))
    self._readers = 0
    self._writers = 0
    self._promote = withPromotion
    self._readerList = []  # List of Reader thread IDs
    self._writerList = []  # List of Writer thread IDs

  def acquire_read(self):
    logging.debug("RWL : acquire_read()")
    """ Acquire a read lock. Blocks only if a thread has
    acquired the write lock. """
    self._read_ready.acquire(  )
    try:
      while self._writers > 0:
        self._read_ready.wait()
      self._readers += 1
    finally:
      self._readerList.append(threading.get_ident())
      self._read_ready.release(  )

  def release_read(self):
    logging.debug("RWL : release_read()")
    """ Release a read lock. """
    self._read_ready.acquire(  )
    try:
      self._readers -= 1
      if not self._readers:
        self._read_ready.notifyAll(  )
    finally:
      self._readerList.remove(threading.get_ident())
      self._read_ready.release(  )

  def acquire_write(self):
    logging.debug("RWL : acquire_write()")
    """ Acquire a write lock. Blocks until there are no
    acquired read or write locks. """
    self._read_ready.acquire(  )   # A re-entrant lock lets a thread re-acquire the lock
    self._writers += 1
    self._writerList.append(threading.get_ident())
    while self._readers > 0:
      # promote to write lock, only if all the readers are trying to promote to writer
      # If there are other reader threads, then wait till they complete reading
      if self._promote and threading.get_ident() in self._readerList and set(self._readerList).issubset(set(self._writerList)):
        break
      else:
        self._read_ready.wait(  )

  def release_write(self):
    logging.debug("RWL : release_write()")
    """ Release a write lock. """
    self._writers -= 1
    self._writerList.remove(threading.get_ident())
    self._read_ready.notifyAll(  )
    self._read_ready.release(  )

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ReadRWLock:
  # Context Manager class for ReadWriteLock
  def __init__(self, rwLock):
    self.rwLock = rwLock

  def __enter__(self):
    self.rwLock.acquire_read()
    return self         # Not mandatory, but returning to be safe

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.rwLock.release_read()
    return False        # Raise the exception, if exited due to an exception

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class WriteRWLock:
  # Context Manager class for ReadWriteLock
  def __init__(self, rwLock):
    self.rwLock = rwLock

  def __enter__(self):
    self.rwLock.acquire_write()
    return self         # Not mandatory, but returning to be safe

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
    self.rwLock.release_write()
    return False        # Raise the exception, if exited due to an exception

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```